# Making get request to fetch list list of books from google books api

Tags: react-native, google-api

**Search file**
as you can see i am making get request to google api, but before rendering this search page it already gives me an error  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.volumeInfo'), as if i remove this {result === undefined ? null : } line and try to run code it give me perfect title of first book in array(as in search() console.log is working perfectly) after making proper search

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import axios from 'axios';
import RenderList from '../components/RenderList';



function SearchScreen() {

    const [term, setTerm] = useState("");
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
    const [errorMessage, setErrormessage] = useState("")


    const search = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${term}:keyes&key=AIzaSyDfYS8u4y8OADwoUIkl0gYOl0SJQ4GLuaA`, {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application-json"
            }
        })
        setResult(res.data.items)
        console.log(res.data.items[0].volumeInfo.title)
    }

    

    return (
        <View>
            <SearchBar 
              term={term} 
              onTermChange={newTerm => setTerm(newTerm)} 
              onTermSubmit={() => search()} 
            />
            {result === undefined ? null : <RenderList result={result} />}
        </View>
    )
}

export default SearchScreen;
```

**Render file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';


function RenderList({result}) {
    return (
        
            <FlatList 
              data='result'
              renderItem={({items}) => {
                  return <Text>{items.volumeInfo.title}</Text>
              }} />
        
    )
}

export default RenderList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the API in useEffect()

```
   useEffect((
apiCall();)=>{},[searchedText])
```

Can you please show the Code of SearchBar?